# determine whether ping has been sent successfully

Tags: java

I am using a jsch library to connect to a server using ssh connection. Then I open an "exec" channel to execute a ping command to ping other devices connected to that server.

e.g.

```
ping 192.168.0.128
```

Then it starts printing out in the console the response which is a string and looks as follows:
- successful ping:

```
PING 192.168.0.128 (192.168.0.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.128: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.128: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.231 ms
```

-unsuccessful ping:

```
PING 192.168.0.126 (192.168.0.126) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.7 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.7 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

How can I handle the output to determine programmatically whether the connection has been successful or not? A regexp pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your channel object call `getExitStatus()`, if it is equal to 0 then the connection was successful, if it was equal to 1 then the connection was not successful.

See http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping for the exit codes.